# Firestore: Adding an element into a Hashmap Field in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In my social app, i want to add all the user's id inside a Map Field.who are my friend or family member.
So when someone accepts friend request  both their document's request map field gets updated.

This would like like this:

```
Users:

    ---User1:
    ----requests{
      -----user2:friend
      -----user3:friend
      -----user4:family
           }
    ---User2:
    ----requests{
      -----user1:friend
      -----user3:friend
      -----user4:family
           }
```

I added this code

```
final DocumentReference dr4 = db.collection("Users").document(UserID);

            dr4.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        DocumentSnapshot ds = task.getResult();
                        if(ds!=null){
                            Object obj = ds.getData().get("requests");
                            Map<String,Object> setter2 = (HashMap<String, Object>) obj;
                            if(setter2==null){
                                setter2 = new HashMap<>();
                            }
                            Map<String,Object> request = new HashMap<>();
                            request.put(ProfileUserID,"family");
                            setter2.put("requests", request);
                            batch.update(dr4,setter2);

                        }
```

This works well when the first user is added to requests. But when the second user gets added, it gets messed up like so:

```
Users:

    ---User1:
    ----user4:family
    ----requests{
      -----user2:friend
             }
```

The old user who was a friend and was inside the requests, now gets out of the requests and becomes a new field of its own, while the new friend gets inside the requests.
What i am i doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**
After some tweaks. Now i can add all the userid's in the requests map.
But now if i have 1 entry in the map, and then add one more, the older entry gets duplicated outside the map

[image: The requests field, with both entires]

[image: The copy of older entry which is now outside the map and is a separate entry.]

Code for this was:

```
db.collection("Users").document(ProfileUserID).get()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
if(task.isSuccessful()){
Map<String, Object> abc = (Map<String, Object>)task.getResult().getData().get("requests");
   if (abc==null){
      abc = new HashMap<>();
   }
   Map<String,Object> req = new HashMap<>();
     req.put(UserID,"family");
     abc.put("requests",req);
db.collection("Users").document(ProfileUserID)
.set(abc,SetOptions.merge())
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
       @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
      if(task.isSuccessful()){
db.collection("Users").document(UserID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
    Map<String, Object> abc2 = (Map<String, Object>)task.getResult().getData().get("requests");
      if (abc2 == null) {
         abc2 = new HashMap<>();
      }
   Map<String, Object> req = new HashMap<>();
   req.put(ProfileUserID, "family");
   abc2.put("requests", req);
db.collection("Users").document(UserID).set(abc2,SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show a screenshot of what exactly the document looks like after both the first and second updates?  Map fields don't just escape their nestings after an update.

Comment: HI @DougStevenson, if you could let me know how to add a map inside a map field. I think i can manage the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a Map<String, Object> to the requests map field, I changed the requests to an array named family & used the FieldValue.arrayUnion() method to increment the userids like so:

```
db.collection("Users").document(ProfileUserID).update("family",FieldValue.arrayUnion(UserID))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the statement `ds.getData().get("requests")` returns: `{ user4:family }`,
and this is assigned to `setter2`.

Than `request` map is being created with value `{ user2:friend }` and this is added to above with `put` method i.e. `{ request: { user2:friend } }`. So this creating structure like this:

`{ user4:family, requests { user2:friend } }`

And this I suppose is the reason of wrong structure. I do not have playground to test it, but I think this should work:

```
if(ds!=null){
    Object obj = ds.getData().get("requests");
    
    Map<String,Object> setter2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,Object> request = new HashMap<>();
                        
    request.put((HashMap<String, Object>) obj) 
    request.put(ProfileUserID,"family");
                        
    setter2.put("requests", request);
    batch.update(dr4,setter2);
}
```

And I am sure this is only one of many ways the issue can be solved.